# Authorization error when assigning role to web app using VSTS

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I am trying to assign role to azure web app using VSTS.

```
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId 976a5114-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-7403ef25ac29 -RoleDefinitionName "Reader" -Scope "/subscriptions/4364666b-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-47158904c439/resourceGroups/devt002RG/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/devt002"
```

Error :

```
2019-03-26T09:26:16.5246563Z ##[error]The client 'a78361e3-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-fb0ced07865c' with object id 'a78361e3-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-fb0ced07865c' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' over scope '/subscriptions/4364666b-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-47158904c439/resourceGroups/devt002RG/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/devt002/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/466c9ad5-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-c0ff4051db14'.
```

I am the owner on the subscription 4364666b-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-47158904c439

Note : Working fine when run using cloud shell.

Comment: Do you use the same service principal to log in both in the VSTS and cloud shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have the owner permission of your subscription first, and then login with the service principal through Azure PowerShell. So you can assign the Reader role to your storage account.

I can reappear the error you got and then achieve your purpose. Below is the screenshot of the process:

The error you got:
[image]

Get the owner permission of your subscription and then login with the service principal in a new PowerShell session:
[image]

Assign the Reader role to your storage account:
[image]

There is an exception but the role has created. 
[image]

Note: When you are in Azure Cloud Shell, then you already login the Azure with your Azure account in default, not the service principal.

Comment: When i run the Connect-AzAccount command it shows me error message - Connect-AzAccount : AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'raj.negi' was not found in the directory 'adb48caa-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-a5e508c807f5'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the 
administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

Comment: @rAJ You should use the object Id, not the application Id.

Comment: I am using 'Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential -Tenant "adb48caa-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-a5e508c807f5" -ServicePrincipal' with tenant id. Where to put the object id?

Comment: @rAJ Sorry, I mean assign the role with the object Id, does your service principal not in the same tenant with your storage account?

Comment: I have only one tenant and using same credential for login in powershell as well as in VSTS.

Comment: @rAJ How do you create the service principal in your tenant?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190750/discussion-between-raj-and-charles-xu).

Comment: Ok got it. Just run the powershell command to assign owner permission on subscription before run the assigning role command. 
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId a78361e3-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-fb0ced07865c -RoleDefinitionName "owner" -Scope "/subscriptions/4364666b-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-47158904c439"